# How to use facet query in CollapsingQParserPlugin in solr?

Tags: solr4

I want to generate facets on the uncollapsed set for a particular facet. Is there any solr query to achieve these functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by tagging the collapse filter, and then excluding the that tag in the particular facet. Say you want to collapse by `group` and facet on `widget`, then you could do:

```
?q=*:*
&fq={!collapse field=group tag=collapse}
&facet=true
&facet.field={!ex=collapse}widget
```